# how to export only JUNIT file with maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I want to test an already compiled jar file (part of an RPM we built) on a test server by running all of the junit tests for the application.  The original application jar doesn't contain the junit tests so I want to export *only* the junit tests into their own jar file and run the tests by passing both application and junit jar files to testrunner.

Unforutnately the Junit tests utilize some helper classes which are imported from jar files listed in my maven pom.  When I try to export my junit jar file through eclipse using the regular export -> jar file method I get the junit tests; but not the additional maven resources the test depend on.  I'm not too familar with maven but I know I can export the entire application using the maven-assembly-plugin plugin.  However, I don't know how to only export the junit tests (and associated resources) without exporting everything.  Obviously for the sake of ensuring a proper test the application jar I want to make sure my junit jar doesn't contain any of the resources already contained in my application jar.

Can anyone help me with the syntax I need to export only the stuff in my src/test folder and it's resources?  We may be doing this process for many different RPM in the future and I'm ideally looking for a method that can be done by the deployment team on any future RPMs, but the individuals deploying may have even less Java/Maven expertise then myself.  So ideally I'm looking for the most easily taught/repeatable method possible.  Not really sure how 'idiot proof' something like this can be made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by what you want to actually do but here it goes anyway.

You can create [a test jar with the jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) as a first option.

Second option would be to just have a separate module that has the tests in it and run the tests of it and potentially create a test jar there as well.

However really my thinking would be why not run the normal build that does the compilation and the test execution already. What more do you actually need?

Update: After your clarification, I would suggest to set up a maven project that contains the junit tests as a source. If you unpack the rpm, put the jar into a maven repository and declare a dependency to it you can run the build with the jar and the tests will get executed against whatever is on the classpath (including the jar from the rpm)...

Comment: because the RPM is going to be installed on different enviroments we want to run the tests when installed on each enviroment so that we know that the program worked on *that* enviroment.  Unfortunately the RPM we will be given, developed by others, won't be built with the JUnit tests so the only way to run the test after an install is if we can make them a seperate jar.

Comment: @dsollen So does this answer solve your issue (specifically the how-to-make-a-test-jar part)?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to try it last night, I'll be trying it now.  Can you tell me how the RPM is suppose to know what is part of the test and what isn't?  i assume it includes anything in the test directory; but how does it decide which dependencies are needed by the test vs those needed by the main application?

Comment: followup: I tried the first test jar option.  It created the junit jar but did not include any of the resource files and dependencies the jar file contained; so I pretty much only got what eclipse was able to build without maven.  Not sure how to make it include the appropriate dependencies; there doesn't seem to be an applicable option for the plugin.